# Change meta description on each page with php after header

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

I ma trying to change dynamically the meta description on each page with php after header.php file.

I currently change my page title by this code:

```
<?php
 require 'config.php';
 include 'logout.php';
 require 'header.php'; 
 $buffer=ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 $title = "Title of each page";
 $buffer = preg_replace('/(<title>)(.*?)(<\/title>)/i', '$1' . $title . '$3', $buffer);
 echo $buffer; 
 //rest of page
?>
```

and is working.

I  tried to do the same for `<meta name="description" content="content">`

by adding the following code exactly under the title one:

```
 $buffer_meta = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 $meta_description = "meta content";
 $buffer_meta = preg_replace('/(<meta name="description" content=")(.*?)(">)/i', '$1' . $meta_description. '$3', $buffer_meta);
 echo $buffer_meta;
```

But is not working.

On `var_dump($buffer_meta)` i get `string 0` a `null` result.

Any feedback?

Comment: go to the header, locate the title tag, append the necessary php,stop using regex for dom manipulation

Comment: Sorry but did get you. What do you mean to append the necessary php?

Comment: why aren't you altering header.php? and place your logic there?

Comment: But still if I do that how am I gonna change the meta desc dynamically depend on page? Also can you please let me know that's the difference of changing it in header or like i am doing? Thank you

Comment: its simpler to alter header.php and it doesn't involve any regex manipulation, its cleaner,fater and easier to read

Comment: can you provide the code for header.php?

Comment: @madalinivascu thank you for that info. So should I use same code in header or you have something quickly to suggest me how it should look like?

Comment: do you know how concatenation works?

Comment: do you know how to place inline php?

Comment: yes and yes @madalinivascu

Comment: you need to move title and the meta variables above the include header.php and in header.php you just use concatenation to output the title & meta

Comment: @madalinivascu but what if I have 50 pages on same file created dynamically? e.g destination?dest_1 / destination?dest_2 ....... Should I use for better database with mata table or having a if/case logic with variable $page and $meta?